# .NET RegEx Patterns (Instagram URL Pattern)

Tags: .net, regex

I've been reading at MSDN about .NET regular expressions. I'm stunned at the possibilities and speechless. I have no idea what the pattern should be to extract the URL below. Can someone with knowledge of .NET regular expressions please help. Thanks.

This is an example of the URL I'm trying to use a pattern on:

img src="http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/a0a2f13eda3c11e2b7ba22000aaa2161_6.jpg

The only constants of these URL's are 'img src="http://', '.com', the other '/' and '_6.jpg'. The other characters in between will all be alphanumeric and contain decimals '.'.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using regular expressions to parse URL-s, use the [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class instead. It has properties to read for each part of the URL and it'll properly parse them.

Regular expressions may become very complicated if you start handling the various different possible URL-s and you'll have a hard time testing all the different possibilities.

For example:

```
string sUrl = "http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/a0...a2161_6.jpg";
Uri oUrl;

if ( Uri.TryCreate ( sUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out oUrl ) )
{
    // TODO use properties of oUrl to inspect the URL
}
```

Comment: I don't think he's trying to validate or parse the URL, he wants to extract information from it, like sub-domain and image name.

Comment: @LuizDamim That's exactly the purpose of the `Uri` class.

Comment: You're right. I have never used the `Uri` class and didn't know about these properties. I'm sorry... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var regex = new Regex("http://[\w\d.]*com/[\w\d]*_6.jpg");
```

usage:

```
if (regex.IsMatch(url))
{
    //your processing here.
}
```

unfortunately there isn't much to go on, more examples and what of the url you need would be helpful.

Comment: @user2510712 Don't use regex for this. Or at least don't use it by itself - it's not the right solution. If your URL-s are diverse, your regex will fail and you'll be back to square one.